# Visual glitches during jQuery.animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm almost done implementing a slide down drawer in jQuery. When you click the handle labeled show, it should expand the drawer downwards, exposing the content. Clicking the handle should slide the drawer back up. It works great except for a couple visual glitches and I don't know why they are happening. Please see my working example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/fKUy9/1/

When you click on the handle, the drawer does slide down as expected but the handle stops short. Also, when sliding up and down, the drawer as a whole jumps up and then down on the page as if the top margin was being modified. Can anyone help me fix this?

Code:

```
(function($){
    $.cabinet = function(options) {
        plugin = this;

        plugin.ui = {};
        plugin.settings = $.extend({}, $.cabinet.prototype.defaultOptions, (typeof options === 'object') ? options : {});

        plugin.content = function(contentCallback){
            contentCallback(plugin.ui.content);
        }

        var init = function() {
            createHTMLElements();
            bindUIEvents();
            attachToDOM();
            mockCSS();
        }

        var createHTMLElements = function() {
            plugin.ui.body = $('body');
            plugin.ui.drawer = $('<div id="drawer" data-expanded="false"></div>');
            plugin.ui.content = $('<div id="drawer-content"></div>');
            plugin.ui.handle = $('<div id="drawer-handle">Show</div>');
        };

        var mockCSS = function() {
            plugin.ui.drawer.css({
                'height': plugin.settings.collapsed_height,
                'width': plugin.settings.drawer_width,
                'margin': '0 auto',
                'position': 'relative',
                'font-family': 'Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif'
            });

            plugin.ui.content.css({
                'background': '#cccccc',
                'height': plugin.settings.collapsed_height,
                'font-size': '.75em'
            });

            plugin.ui.handle.css({
                'height': plugin.settings.collapsed_height,
                'width': plugin.settings.drawer_width,
                'position': 'absolute',
                'bottom': '-1px',
                'left': (plugin.ui.drawer.width()/2) - (plugin.ui.handle.width()/2),
                'text-align': 'center',
                'background': '#333',
                'color': '#fff',
                'cursor': 'pointer',
                'font-size': '.7em',
                'padding-top': '5px',
                'padding-bottom': '5px'
            });
        };

        var bindUIEvents = function() {
            plugin.ui.handle.on('click', function(e){
                plugin.ui.drawer.data('expanded', plugin.ui.drawer.data('expanded') === true ? false : true);
                plugin.ui.handle.data('label', plugin.ui.drawer.data('expanded') === true ? 'Hide' : 'Show');

                if(plugin.ui.drawer.data('expanded') === true) {
                    expandDrawer();
                } else {
                    collapseDrawer();
                }
            });
        };

        var attachToDOM = function() {
            var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

            plugin.ui.drawer.appendTo(fragment);
            plugin.ui.content.appendTo(plugin.ui.drawer);
            plugin.ui.handle.appendTo(plugin.ui.drawer);

            plugin.ui.body.prepend(fragment);
        };

        var collapseDrawer = function() {
            var shared_animiations = {
                'height': '-='+plugin.settings.content_height
            }

            plugin.ui.drawer.animate($.extend({}, shared_animiations));

            plugin.ui.content.animate($.extend({
                'padding': 0,
                'overflow': 'hidden'
            }, shared_animiations));

            plugin.ui.handle.text(plugin.ui.handle.data('label'));
        };

        var expandDrawer = function() {
            var shared_animiations = {
                'height': '+='+plugin.settings.content_height
            }

            plugin.ui.drawer.animate($.extend({}, shared_animiations));

            plugin.ui.content.animate($.extend({
                'padding': 25,
            }, shared_animiations));

            plugin.ui.handle.text(plugin.ui.handle.data('label'));
        };

        init();

        return plugin;
    }

    $.cabinet.prototype.defaultOptions = {
        drawer_width: 750,
        content_height: 200,
        handle_height: 15,
        drawer_height: 30
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You aren't seeing this? http://i.imgur.com/K8fS5ek.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@danielepolencic is basically right. The reason is the padding and that you shared the same animation values for both drawer and content. That is why the padding is applied after the height animation is finished.
If you separate those values and subtract top and bottom padding from the animation height for the drawer, it should be the desired effect.
I did an update to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fKUy9/2/) .

Did that help?

```
var content_animiations = {
        'height':  plugin.settings.content_height
    },
    drawer_animiations = {
        'height':  plugin.settings.content_height + 50
    };


    plugin.ui.content.animate($.extend({
        'padding': 25,
    }, content_animiations))


    plugin.ui.drawer.animate($.extend({}, drawer_animiations));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that when jQuery animates `plugin.ui.content` it changes the `height` AND the `padding`. When the animation stops, for a reason that I still need to understand, the proper padding is reapplied and suddenly you can see the glitch.

I have no idea why that happens, but I guess I know how you could solve it. Do not animate the `padding` in `plugin.ui.content` but create an inner div and apply the padding there. It should do the trick.